Book read a while ago that was about something called "Furrorballs" or "Firey Balls"
The book was had something to do with what it called "furror balls" which were basically UFOs or drones, they were first spotted during world War 2. I forget what happens in the book, but I think the people behind the "furror balls" had very advanced technology and were basically blackmailing all the governments of the world. And they would kidnap scientists. They had a base in the Antarctic, and lived very long lives due to advanced technology.

I suspect you are referring to "foo fighters"

The term foo fighters was used by Allied aircraft pilots during World War II to describe various unidentified flying objects or mysterious aerial phenomena seen in the skies over both the European and Pacific theaters of operations.

The Projekt Saucer series by W.A. Harbinson includes the elements you describe
Projekt Saucer series

Projekt Saucer I: Inception (1991)
Projekt Saucer II: Phoenix (1995)
Projekt Saucer III: Genesis (1980)
Projekt Saucer IV: Millennium (1995)
Projekt Saucer V: Resurrection (1999)

From an amazon review of Genesis

While Genesis is the third book in the Projekt Saucer series, it is the first one Harbinson wrote, and as such it was this book that started the brilliant series.
Starting off with a prologue where Allied pilots in 1944 encounter mysterious glowing objects (the feuerballs or "Foo fighters"), the story then moves onto the main plot, which is set from 1974-1979.
The main characters of the story are two American UFO investigators- the young Robert Stanford and the elderly Frederick Epstein. Also featured is an ordinary guy from England, called Richard Watson, who has a not-so-ordinary experience when he is abducted by one of Wilson's flying saucers.
For those not familiar with the series, the character John Wilson is the main focus of the entire series- the man who runs the ultra-advanced saucer base in Antarctica and hopes to eventually take over the whole world.
After Epstein mysteriously disappears, Stanford goes on a quest to find his old friend and also get to the bottom of the whole flying saucer issue. His journey takes him from the fields of Texas, to the sweltering jungles of Paraguay, and eventually to the frozen wastes of Antarctica.

